# How to display specific data of JSON in andorid studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner in app development and trying to create an app to show latest movie releases based on user's watchlist and genre interest. I am using the OMdb (http://www.omdbapi.com/)
api: [http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&](http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=%5Byourkey%5D&)
The json has data for only one movie instead of hundreds(can somebody plz tell me why) and I just want to extract the title of the movie.

Also if anybody knows a better free api please let me know.

```java
public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    String data;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=e70eecd3");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputstream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        MainActivity.txt.setText(this.data);
    }
}
```

JSON data

```json
{
  "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
  "Year": "2017",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "05 May 2017",
  "Runtime": "136 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi",
  "Director": "James Gunn",
  "Writer": "James Gunn, Dan Abnett (based on the Marvel comics by), Andy Lanning (based on the Marvel comics by), Steve Englehart (Star-Lord created by), Steve Gan (Star-Lord created by), Jim Starlin (Gamora and Drax created by), Stan Lee (Groot created by), Larry Lieber (Groot created by), Jack Kirby (Groot created by), Bill Mantlo (Rocket Raccoon created by), Keith Giffen (Rocket Raccoon created by), Steve Gerber (Howard the Duck created by), Val Mayerik (Howard the Duck created by)",
  "Actors": "Chris Pratt, Zoe Saldana, Dave Bautista, Vin Diesel",
  "Plot": "The Guardians struggle to keep together as a team while dealing with their personal family issues, notably Star-Lord's encounter with his father the ambitious celestial being Ego.",
  "Language": "English",
  "Country": "USA",
  "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 15 wins & 56 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM0NTc0NzItM2FlYS00YzEwLWE0YmUtNTA2ZWIzODc2OTgxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgwNzIyNzg@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "7.6/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "85%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "67/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore": "67",
  "imdbRating": "7.6",
  "imdbVotes": "548,890",
  "imdbID": "tt3896198",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "22 Aug 2017",
  "BoxOffice": "$389,804,217",
  "Production": "Walt Disney Pictures",
  "Website": "N/A",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

Comment: can you give us the json response of the api?

Comment: @SideegMoHammed I edited the post with the response I also noticed the api is only fetching one movie data but I want all of them can you plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm unsure of what you'd like to do with this data, how many responses you're hoping for, or any other constraints on this particular application - here's a quick method of how you could go about extracting the title for a particular film.

### Basic Approach:

Firstly, the data might be easiest to manage if you use some of AndroidStudio's JSON objects (located inside the [org.json](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary) package).

Let's use this response hypothetically (taken from the OMDb API):

```
{"Title":"Blade Runner","Year":"1982","Rated":"R","Released":"25 Jun 1982","Runtime":"117 min","Genre":"Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller","Director":"Ridley Scott","Writer":"Hampton Fancher (screenplay), David Webb Peoples (screenplay), Philip K. Dick (novel)","Actors":"Harrison Ford, Rutger Hauer, Sean Young, Edward James Olmos","Plot":"A blade runner must pursue and terminate four replicants who stole a ship in space, and have returned to Earth to find their creator.","Language":"English, German, Cantonese, Japanese, Hungarian, Arabic","Country":"USA","Awards":"Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 12 wins & 16 nominations.","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzQzMzJhZTEtOWM4NS00MTdhLTg0YjgtMjM4MDRkZjUwZDBlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.1/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"90%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"84/100"}],"Metascore":"84","imdbRating":"8.1","imdbVotes":"679,274","imdbID":"tt0083658","Type":"movie","DVD":"N/A","BoxOffice":"N/A","Production":"Blade Runner Partnership, Ladd Company","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}
```

If we have this JSON response stored in the variable `data`, we can create a JSONObject - making it much easier to extract the data we want:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data) // maps JSON data to new JSONObject
String title = jsonObject.getString("Title"); // the string 'title' would hold the value "Blade Runner"
```

Using the JSONObjects you could extract any number of key value pairs from the returned data. Just ensure that you're aware of handling different [data types](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#get(java.lang.String)) if that's something you'll need to do later in your development (ex: `jsonElement.getInt("IntegerKey")` for integer values, `jsonElement.getJSONObject("ObjectName")` if you have nested JSONObjects within your response, etc.).

### Approach for multi-object responses:

If you're expecting to return multiple JSON Objects from a response (and the response is an array), it may be better to run a separate method to do all your data processing - or at least process them in a more defined loop structure:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
JSONObject jsonElement;
String title, year;
// a for loop can iterate through all json objects within the returned 'data' string
for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonElement = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    title = jsonElement.getString("Title");
    year = jsonElement.getString("Year");
}
// after this is processed you could store it in some data structure or pass it to another part of the application
```

Essentially, I've always found the AndroidStudio JSONObjects to be particularly useful. Please let me know if that helps at all or how it ends up working for you!

Comment: getElement method is giving an error of Rename reference can you give a work around

Comment: Try the edit above, I realized that the response is only returning a singular object at the highest level, so it may be redundant to add it to a `JSONArray` right away. Although after looking into this type of error, it could be signifying an issue with packages or dependencies; I'd definitely take a look into it if it persists. However, I hope that fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to bark Jason
and
https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis
Link api free

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the data from stirng to json like these

```
 JsonObject jsonResponse= new JsonObject(this.data);
```

and then you can get the title Property from it

```
MainActivity.txt.setText(jsonResponse.getString("Title"));
```

Comment: getProperty method is giving Rename Reference Error can you help

Comment: i edit my answer try getString insted of getProperty